# How do I configure FreeLAN to work as a VPN?

Tags: vpn, lan

I have a computer at home (Windows 10 Home Single Language), to which I have access from the administrator, which is connected by WiFi to the operator that gives me Internet (Movistar), which assigns an IP. I do not have access to the Internet operator's modem.

I want to configure FreeLAN to obtain services such as provided by hide.me or tunnelbear, since these allow me to change my location IP, so I can access web sites that are restricted in my country.

I installed FreeLAN, but I do not know how to create the certificates or the rest of the steps.  Can you give me an explanation, or step-by-step commands?

PS - I already checked the different pages and explanations, but I can not find the cmd commands to configure. Everything is installed by default.